# How to use table row values as function parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Table `ko` is used to pass parameters to `crtKAIVE` function.
This table has always single row.

I tried code below but got error

```
ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
LINE 15: select * from ko, crtkaive(ko.doktyyp)
```

How to fix this so that ko can used to pass parameters to crtkaive ?
Postgres 9.1 and later versions are used.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.crtKAIVE(
_doktyybid text default 'GVY'
)
RETURNS TABLE (
id integer
)
AS $f_crkaive$
select 1
$f_crkaive$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;

create temp  table ko ( doktyyp text ) on commit drop;

insert into ko values ('G');

select * from ko, crtkaive(ko.doktyyp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `lateral join` introduced in Postgres 9.3. The syntax is incorrect in earlier versions.

In Postgres 9.1 you can try

```
select doktyyp, crtkaive(doktyyp) from ko;
```

or

```
select * from crtkaive((select doktyyp from ko));
```